# How to make nuget package:moderenwpfui generate only needed language files.(WPF project)

Tags: wpf, vb.net

**How to make nuget package:moderenwpfui generate only needed language files.**
The repository for this nuget package is https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf .
**When I generate my app, a lot of language files will be generated. Is there a way to generate only the language I need or preset the language file to the language I use?**
The following are all the files generated in the Debug directory, the one without the suffix is the folder, the folder contains the dll library for the language files

```
af-ZA
am-ET
ar-SA
az-Latn-AZ
be-BY
bg-BG
bn-BD
bs-Latn-BA
ca-ES
cs-CZ
da-DK
de-DE
dotnetCampus.FileDownloader.dll
el-GR
en-GB
es-ES
es-MX
et-EE
eu-ES
fa-IR
fi-FI
file
fr-CA
fr-FR
gl-ES
ha-Latn-NG
he-IL
hi-IN
hr-HR
hu-HU
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.pdb
id-ID
is-IS
it-IT
ja-JP
ka-GE
kk-KZ
km-KH
kn-IN
ko-KR
lo-LA
lt-LT
lv-LV
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.dll
mk-MK
ml-IN
ModernWpf.Controls.dll
ModernWpf.dll
ms-MY
nb-NO
nl-NL
nn-NO
myapp.exe
myapp.exe.config
myapp.pdb
myapp.xml
pl-PL
pt-BR
pt-PT
ro-RO
ru-RU
runtimes
sk-SK
sl-SI
sq-AL
sr-Latn-RS
sv-SE
sw-KE
System.Drawing.Common.dll
System.ValueTuple.dll
ta-IN
te-IN
th-TH
tr-TR
uk-UA
uz-Latn-UZ
vi-VN
WPFUI.dll
zh-CN
zh-TW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Project>References you will find `ModernWpf` and `ModernWpf.Controls`. You need to set the property `Copy Local` to `False` for both of them.

[image]

Before you do that, backup these files and copy them manually to debug folder after doing the above steps.

```
ModernWpf.Controls.dll
ModernWpf.dll
```

You will get errors if you don't do this.